# After adding repository to overlay, package still not in package path

Tags: zsh, ros

I'm currently getting into ROS and rosbuild and as start I'm working trough this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/fuerte/Installation/Overlays), but I'm stuck at:

3. Adding repositories to the overlay

I did the following things before that point:

1. `rosws init . /opt/ros/kinetic`
2. `source setup.zsh`
3. `mkdir sandbox`
4. `myros rosws set sandbox`
   Now the basic Overlay is set up, i can access the package roscpp with `roscd roscpp` and after that I'm able to return to my new overlay with `roscd` - so i add a repository
5. `rosws set turtlebot --git -u https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot`
6. `rosws update`

My .rosinstall file looks like this at this moment:

```
setup-file: {local-name: /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.sh}
other: {local-name: sandbox}
git: {local-name: turtlebot, uri: 'https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot'}
```

After that the Tutorial says:

> After re-sourcing setup.bash the new overlayed stack turtlebot should be in your package path, i.e. roscd turtlebot should switch to the directory ~/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot.

If i want to use `roscd turtlebot` I'm getting:

> roscd: No such package 'turtlebot'

Because the tutorial says

> After re-sourcing setup.bash should be in your package path...

I tried resourcing with `source source.zsh` but thats now working either.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing a tutorial on ROS Fuerte, but you seem to use ROS Kinetic. Fuerte was released in 2012, Kinetic in 2016. There are **major** differences between the two .. one is that `rosbuild` is not the build system of choice anymore.

I suggest you forget all about `rosbuild` (replaced by `catkin`) and `rosws` (replaced by `wstool`) and start fresh from http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials, notably http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment (chapter 3) with `catkin` selected.

If you really want to be using the latest stuff, consider even ditching the mentioned `catkin_make` and take a look at [`catkin_tools`](http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)